# Divide operation in spark using RDD or dataframe

Tags: apache-spark

Suppose there is a dataset with some number of rows.

I need to find out the Heterogeneity i.e.

`distinct number of rows divide by total number of rows.`

Please help me with spark query to execute the same.

Comment: Simply find the number of distinct rows (`df.distinct.count`) and divide by number of rows (`df.count`).

Answer (score 1):

Dataset and dataframe supports distinct function which finds distinct rows in the dataset.

So essentially you need to do

```
val heterogeneity = dataset.distinct.count / dataset.count
```

Only thing is if the dataset is big the distinct could be expensive and you might need to  set the spark shuffle partition correctly.

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if it has worked for you